# Can't compile CyanogenMod 13

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to compile CyanogenMod from scratch with the help of [this](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_angler) guide. I've done most of the steps without any errors, but at the `brunch angler` step, I keep getting this error:

```
Building with Jack: /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v13-ics-mr1_intermediates/classes.jack
host Executable: llvm-rs-cc (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/llvm-rs-cc_intermediates/llvm-rs-cc)
Building with Jack: /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/com.android.gallery3d.common2_intermediates/classes.jack
target Symbolic: libssl (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/product/angler/symbols/system/lib64/libssl.so)
target StaticLib: libLLVMAArch64CodeGen (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/product/angler/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libLLVMAArch64CodeGen_intermediates/libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a)
Launching background server java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms2560m -XX:+TieredCompilation -jar /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack-launcher.jar -cp /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack.jar com.android.jack.server.JackSimpleServer
target StaticLib: libLLVMAArch64Info (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/product/angler/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libLLVMAArch64Info_intermediates/libLLVMAArch64Info.a)
Launching background server java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms2560m -XX:+TieredCompilation -jar /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack-launcher.jar -cp /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack.jar com.android.jack.server.JackSimpleServer
target StaticLib: libLLVMAArch64Desc (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/product/angler/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libLLVMAArch64Desc_intermediates/libLLVMAArch64Desc.a)
target StaticLib: libLLVMAArch64AsmParser (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/product/angler/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libLLVMAArch64AsmParser_intermediates/libLLVMAArch64AsmParser.a)
target StaticLib: libLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter (/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/product/angler/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter_intermediates/libLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter.a)
ERROR: /home/hexafluoride/android/system/packages/apps/Gallery2/gallerycommon/src/com/android/gallery3d/exif/ExifData.java:1: The type java.lang.Object cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath
ERROR: /home/hexafluoride/android/system/packages/apps/Gallery2/gallerycommon/src/com/android/gallery3d/exif/ExifData.java:19: The import android cannot be resolved
* lots of errors saying that basic types can't be resolved after this *
```

And then make fails. I've tried doing `make showcommands`, and this is the output:

```
if [ -s /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-jellybean_intermediates/jack-rsc/java-source-list-uniq ] ; then export tmpEcjArg="@/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-jellybean_intermediates/jack-rsc/java-source-list-uniq"; else export tmpEcjArg=""; fi;  JACK_VM_COMMAND="java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms2560m -XX:+TieredCompilation  -jar /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack-launcher.jar " JACK_JAR="/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/framework/jack.jar" /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/bin/jack @build/core/jack-default.args --verbose error  -g  --classpath /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v16_intermediates/classes.jack:/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/sdk_v16_intermediates/classes.jack:/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-ics-mr1_intermediates/classes.jack --import /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-ics-mr1_intermediates/classes.jack  -D jack.import.resource.policy=keep-first -D jack.import.type.policy=keep-first -D jack.java.source.version=1.7  --output-jack /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-jellybean_intermediates/classes.jack   $tmpEcjArg || ( rm -f /home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-jellybean_intermediates/classes.jack ; exit 41 )
ERROR: /home/hexafluoride/android/system/frameworks/support/v4/jellybean/android/support/v4/app/NavUtilsJB.java:0: The type android.app.Notification cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath
build/core/java.mk:636: recipe for target '/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-jellybean_intermediates/classes.jack' failed
make: *** [/home/hexafluoride/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v4-jellybean_intermediates/classes.jack] Error 41
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem probably was because I abruptly interrupted the build process because of a hang, and then tried to continue building from there.

I did a `make clobber && brunch angler` and it built successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much! 2 years later this made my day.